# Search for a pattern in a filename in linux

Tags: linux, string, search, filenames

Here are a few example filenames:

> 1_0_1_2A34_8_70_1680000_0_0_0.png
>
> 1_0_1_1_1A2C_1_5A2F16_0_0_0.png
>
> 1_0_1_3EC_6_601_D7A0000_0_0_0.png
>
> 1_0_1_152D_7E3_2_11A2F26_0_0_0.png

Firstly, I am trying to make linux recognize the filenames as 10 column's of text seperated by underscores "_".

For example:

> col1_col2_col3_col4_col5_col6_col7_col8_col9_col10.png

Then I want to tell linux to search for a string (e.g. "11A") in the first 3 characters of column 7 of the filename's.

I have thousands of these files and if I do a regular search for "11A" I will get matches for files that contain 11A but in the 4th, 5th & 7th column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Perl script (let's call it `match7th.pl`) that will print out any lines where the 7th field matches the pattern given (e.g. `11A`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $pat = qr/$ARGV[0]/;
while (<STDIN>) {
    my (undef, undef, undef, undef, undef, undef, $seventh) = split /_/;
    print if defined($seventh) && $seventh =~ $pat;
}
```

Run it like this:

```
find . -name '*.png' | perl match7th.pl 11A
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you for your fast reply. I will test this now and report back..I was editing original question when you replied to request that the search only looked in the first 3 characters of column 7.  Could I incorperate that into the find command or within the script?

Comment: Not working? Let me know what's wrong, it may be an easy fix.

Comment: That worked a treat my friend, now I just need to move the matching results to a new folder... The old way I was using find like this: `find /folder -type f -iname "11A" \ -exec mv -t /new_folder/25.5E {} \+`

Comment: Just to clear up, that perl script does exactly what i want in regards to the search, it would be great if I could add 2 or more search strings at once.. e.g. `find . -name '*.png' | perl match7th.pl 11A,D7A` but this is not working.. and finally I would like to move the results to a new folder..  Thank you for your time Chris

Comment: You can use more than one search by using the `|` regex operator, for example, `perl match7th.pl '11A|D7A'` (don't forget the quotes or else your shell will misinterpret the `|`). You can then pipe to `xargs mv -t /new_folder/25.5E` to do the move.

Comment: All together: `find . -name '*.png' | perl match7th.pl '11A|D7A' | xargs mv -t /new_folder/25.5E`

Comment: By the way, relating to your other post, where I mentioned that `sed` uses basic regular expressions (BRE) (but could switch to extended regular expressions (ERE) using the `-r` option), in Perl, it uses an even more enhanced regular expression system. So you could convert your other `sed` script to use Perl instead and get awesome regexes, if you wanted to.

Comment: OK Chris, I take all that on board and I will test as soon as possible..  One thing that I was wondering..  Could I run that pearl script from within my master script or does it have to be an external file?  What I mean is, could it be contained in a standard linux script rather than calling an external .pl script?  One way or another my problem is solved so this is more out of curiosity than anything..

Comment: `find . -name '*.png' | perl match7th.pl '11A|D7A' | xargs mv -t /new_folder/25.5E`  Worked a treat & has knocked paragraphs off my master script...  the only problem was a few files that contained the 11A or D7A but in the middle or end of the string.  Is it possible to tell linux only to search for the 11A or D7A in the first 3 characters of the seventh column??

Comment: Yes, use `'^11A|^D7A'`.

Comment: As for running inline, in theory you could, but it would make your main script ugly.

Comment: Thanks again Chris.  I just noticed a problem when calling on the script multiple times.. The first time runs fine but the second time I get error `mv: missing file operand`  Do I have to exit out of match7th.pl each time or something like that?  I ran `find . -name '*.png' | perl match7th.pl 'E08' | xargs mv -t /var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/1111` then `find . -name '*.png' | perl match7th.pl '300000|302C|302F|3030|3031|310000|312F|320000' | xargs mv -t /var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/2222` and i get `mv: missing file operand`

Comment: "Missing file operand" means no files matched, so there's nothing to move.